# Problema con los logs de storage, laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

una consulta comunidad, estoy tratando de ver un error por logs de un proyecto con laravel 6, sin embargo no me genera el archivo en la carpeta: storage/logs, estoy con linux, di todos los permisos a las carpetas pero nada, en .env se tiene:
LOG_CHANNEL=stack y en logging.php esta asi:

```
'channels' => [
    'stack' => [
        'driver' => 'stack',
        'channels' => ['daily'],
        'ignore_exceptions' => false,
    ]
```

que me faltaria para poder capturar los logs?

Gracias anticipadas

Comment: Tal vez no lo escribe porque el problema ocurre dentro de un try catch y como tal cuando atrapas el error no lo escribes en un log de la forma que indica la documentación **Log::channel('slack')->info('Something happened!');**

Comment: Gracias alberto pude resorverlo viendo los logs en mi servidor lampp que tenia instalado.